# Converting a single and two digit string into a LocalDate Format

Tags: java, sql

I have an application where the users have been able to select a pre-defined set of months from 1 to 12, which is then passed into a string.
Now I would like to convert that string into LocalDate, but I don't want my users to lose the data that has already been saved in the database. Is there some way to convert single or double digit data into LocalDate?

Eg. if the user has previously entered "2", then that data needs to be changed to 2022-02-01. If the user has previously entered "10" then this will be changed to 2022-10-01 and so on.

I am familiar with the formatting itself

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class LocalDateExample1_ISO_LOCAL_DATE {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;
        String date = "2019-10-12";
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);

        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(localDate);
        System.out.println(formatter.format(localDate));
    }
}
```

Comment: "Is there some way to convert single or double digit data into LocalDate?" <- Only if you define clear rules on what the values for year and day should be set to. Like, you never explained to us why "2" should result in "2022-02-01". Is the year always 2022 and day always 1 or how did you arrive with that result?

Comment: Convert the string into `int` (`Integer.parseInt`) and then construct the date using `LocalDate.of(2022,month,1)`. Isn't it what you want?

Answer (score 1):

> I have an application where the users have been able to select a pre-defined set of months from 1 to 12, which is then passed into a string.

You should re-consider this unnecessary int-to-string-to-int conversion.

Anyhow, to create a new LocalDate with year and day of month fixed, month being a parameter (e.g. `monthAsString`):

```
var localDate = LocalDate.of(2022, Integer.parseInt(monthAsString), 1);
```

To change the Month of an existing LocalDate:

```
var localDate = localDate.withMonth(Integer.parseInt(monthAsString));
```

Be aware that you need to check for

- monthString being null
- monthString being not parseable into an int
- parsed monthString is out-of-range [1,12]
- parsed month string will result in an invalid date like 31.02.2022